# build image from tarball

Tags: node.js, docker, tar

I create a tar archive from within my working dir

```
tar -chv . --exclude='build/tarball.tar' > build/tarball.tar
```

and would like to create an image from this

```
sudo docker build - < build/tarball.tar
```

This is my dockerfile

```
FROM node:8.11.3-slim
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y
ENV GOSU_VERSION 1.10
RUN set -x \
    && dpkgArch="$(dpkg --print-architecture | awk -F- '{ print $NF }')" \
    && wget -O /usr/local/bin/gosu "https://github.com/tianon/gosu/releases/download/$GOSU_VERSION/gosu-$dpkgArch" \
    && wget -O /usr/local/bin/gosu.asc "https://github.com/tianon/gosu/releases/download/$GOSU_VERSION/gosu-$dpkgArch.asc" \
    && export GNUPGHOME="$(mktemp -d)" \
    && gpg --keyserver ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-keys B42F6819007F00F88E364FD4036A9C25BF357DD4 \
    && gpg --batch --verify /usr/local/bin/gosu.asc /usr/local/bin/gosu \
    && rm -r "$GNUPGHOME" /usr/local/bin/gosu.asc \
    && chmod +x /usr/local/bin/gosu \
    && gosu nobody true

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY . /usr/src/app
# node-user comes from node-docker-image
RUN chown -R node:node /usr/src/app
EXPOSE 8080
ENV NODE_ENV production
CMD ["gosu","node","npm","start"]
```

However starting the images failes because node throws an error:

```
Error: Cannot find module '..'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
```

If I create the image from the directory itself it works, why doesn't it work if I point to the tar archive?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your docker version, I think you might want to be using docker [import](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/import/):

```
docker import build/tarball.tar mynode:latest
```